# Aligning combination of numbers and parentheses in siunitx table

Tags: horizontal-alignment, siunitx

I have this table and would like to align the columns by the parentheses. Note that I want to have both the number and the percentages (in parentheses) in one column.

**Input**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
   \begin{table}[]
     \centering
     \sisetup{
        }
     \caption{My caption}
     \begin{tabular}{@{}S@{}}
        \toprule
        No \\ \midrule
        55 (11\%) \\
        47 (9\%) \\
        1 (3\%) \\
        1115 (22\%) \\
        36 (7\%) \\
        435 (9\%) \\
        123 (25\%) \\
        1438 (29\%) \\ \bottomrule
     \end{tabular}
  \end{table}   
\end{document}
```

**Output**
[image]

I know the `siunitx` package is useful for aligning in tables, but I don't know what to use as the input in `\sisetup{}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \sisetup{
    table-figures-integer = 4                      ,
    table-figures-decimal = 0                      ,
    table-space-text-post = {~(\SI{99}{\percent})} ,
    table-number-alignment = center
  }
  \def\x#1{~(\SI{#1}{\percent})}
  \caption{My Caption}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}S@{}}
    \toprule
    {No}        \\ \midrule
    55   \x{11} \\
    47   \x9    \\
    1    \x3    \\
    1115 \x{22} \\
    36   \x7    \\
    435  \x9    \\
    123  \x{25} \\
    1438 \x{29} \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}   
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 4):

I do not know another solution but tweaking around with two columns. Is there a reasons why you do not want to use two?

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \caption{My caption}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}S[table-format=4.0]@{\ }l@{}}
            \toprule
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{No} \\ 
            \midrule
            55 &(\SI{11}{\percent}) \\
            47 &(\SI{9}{\percent}) \\
            1 &(\SI{3}{\percent}) \\
            1115 &(\SI{22}{\percent}) \\
            36 &(\SI{7}{\percent}) \\
            435 &(\SI{9}{\percent}) \\
            123 &(\SI{25}{\percent}) \\
            1438 &(\SI{29}{\percent}) \\ 
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}   
\end{document}
```

This is quite easy, I think.

[image]

I have added the package `caption` which gets the vertical spacing right. I would leave away the `@{}` infront and after the columns, but this is a matter of taste.

The table still looks bad as the percentage numbers are not aligned correctly. I would prefer something of the following:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{My caption}
    \begin{tabular}{S[table-format=4.0]S[table-format=2.0]}
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{No} \\ 
        \cmidrule(lr){1-2}
        {Number of votes} & {Corr. in \si{\percent}} \\
        \midrule
        55 & 11 \\
        47 & 9 \\
        1 & 3 \\
        1115 & 22 \\
        36 & 7 \\
        435 & 9 \\
        123 & 25 \\
        1438 & 29 \\ 
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}   
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Summary of people saying "No"}
    \begin{tabular}{S[table-format=4.0]S[table-format=2.0]}
        \toprule
        {Number of votes} & {Corr. in \si{\percent}} \\
        \midrule
        55 & 11 \\
        47 & 9 \\
        1 & 3 \\
        1115 & 22 \\
        36 & 7 \\
        435 & 9 \\
        123 & 25 \\
        1438 & 29 \\ 
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```